# Trouble in initializing excel code for finding a certain value (KeyError)

Tags: pandas

**EDIT**

When I try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_data = pd.read_csv("TEST2.csv")

print(csv_data['Age'])
```

It gives the following error:

```
KeyError 'Age'
```

Why is that?

Comment: Probably you are selecting a column that is not included in your dataframe or it is misspelled. Check it

Comment: It actually turns out that I misplaced the file itself rather than the name of the column. Anyway, thanks for the info!